# Get a select field to show other select fields based on id of selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working with material-ui and React. I have a `SelectField` that is part of a component which is a grandchild of the parent component. What I need is to take the value of the item in the `SelectField` and then use that to display information in another `SelectField` which is a child of this component so a great grandchild of the parent component if you will.

I need to use the value I get from the first `SelectField` to make an API request to get the info that I need to show in the next `SelectField`.

I can successfully get the value from the first `SelectField` but I am struggling to figure how I can get it to show in the child component.

If you could help me out I would appreciate it.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Could you redefine "display information in another SelectField"? you talk about the field value or options? Could you give a simple code example of how you display the select field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I created an array and when I select the value from the first `SelectField` I updated the state of the array with the values that I wanted to populate the next `SelectField` with and passed it back from the parent component as props.

Answer (score 1):

Put the value of your two fields in a state and fill your select fields with thoses values. Create a callback that will call `this.setState()` to modify the value of the second field when the first one is modified. Attach this callback on yout first field with the property `onChange`. As a result, the second select field will have a new value. you have an example [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. I need the second select field to be populated with items after the choice in the first one is made.

Comment: What you want is actually having the select field populated with options? You can use [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) to programatically insert new option in a select field.

Comment: Putting your second select field options in a state, you can, when rendering the second select field, and without react-select, loop on the available options to display the list of options.

Comment: Yeah I know that! Have used it before in another project but I'm using material-ui components throughout the rest of this app, so ideally I would like to avoid having to use a different style of input just for this part of it.

Comment: Ok. And what about puting options in a state and looping in the rendered top display each options?

Comment: Well yeah I guess that is what I'm trying to do but I think I'm just confusing myself on how I can actually do it due to how deeply nested the child components are. Would you like to see some code to get a better idea of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Not to worry I figured it out myself!

Comment: Good. For other to know what help you, could you put the solution here?